# How to use Performance Profiler with Instrumentation on Asp.net Core app in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, instrumentation, visual-studio-2022

How do you get instrumentation performance data from an ASP.NET Core web app using VS 2022 tools?

We now an app with an ASP.NET Core Web API and MVC app pair. These run locally under IIS Express and use Visual Studio 2022 for diagnostics. I tried to instrument these and cannot figure out the process. I assume you have to run the instrumentation process against the dll then attach to IIS Express once it's running, but I've not found the steps to do that. The old methods I've used on .NET Framework, cli tools, don't seem to work with .NET Core apps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this really needs to be answers